# Rails rest-client put getting 400 bad request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

In a Rails app, I need to read a seed number from another application and then update the seed by 1 using a REST interface.  I'm using the gem 'rest-client'.

I can read the seed number OK using this:

```
      <% xml_data = RestClient.get "http://www.xxxxx.com/maxrest/rest/os/mxautokey?_lid=mxintadm&_lpwd=mxintadm&autokeyname=WORKORDERNUM&ORGID=AAAA" %>
      <% doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_data)%>
      <% prefix = doc.at("PREFIX").text %>
      <% seed = doc.at("SEED").text %>
      <% wonum = prefix + seed %>
```

But, I'm trying to put back a new seed using this (at first I'm just trying to use a hard coded number):

```
<% RestClient.put "http://www.xxxxx.com/maxrest/rest/os/mxautokey?_lid=mxintadm&_lpwd=mxintadm&autokeyname=WORKORDERNUM&ORGID=AAAA", {:seed => 38980} %>
```

I get back - 400 Bad Request

I appreciate the help!

Comment: 400 Bad Request looks like a server problem. The signature for your request should be: put(url, payload, headers = {}, &block) - most likely an url for PUT does not take the parameters you list, but only a payload. Another issue might be that you miss authentication. Can you provide more details on the PUT request specs ?

Comment: what does:  RestClient.put "http://www.xxxxx.com/maxrest/rest/os/mxautokey",{:seed => 38980} give ?

Comment: another thing: You can test this from your console; doing calls like this in a view template is considered bad style... in MVC, the controller is a start to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the help - Sorry I haven't posted lately - been out of town.  The put RestClient.put "xxxxx.com/maxrest/rest/os/mxautokey";,{:seed => 38980} gave me unexpected ',' - So, I tried removing a comma and got - 400 bad request.

Comment: I tried this and it executed OK, but didn't update the number:    <% RestClient.put "http://xxxxx.com/maxrest/rest/mbo/autokey/11?_lid=mxintadm&_lpwd=mxintadm",{:seed => 38980} %>  I'm going to search the logs for the system I'm trying to update.

Comment: I found this documentation:  The following method updates the assetspec business object, which is a child of asset. The value is changed to new_value and the description is changed to my_new_description:
PUT maxrest/rest/mbo/assetpec/5678 HTTP/1.1
value=my_new_value&description=my_new_description